# VueJs2 Query Params Not Passing

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to code password-forget,reset system. In the password reset step, token is sending via url like that;

```
http://link-to-app/reset-password?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpX
```

In vuejs side. I want to get this token params but I can not. I try that;

```
created() {
    console.log(this.$route.params); // Empty Object {}
},
```

Also I try to redirect with query params with `router.push`, it is redirecting but not sending query params;

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/reset-password', params: { token : 1234 } })
```

|

```
http://link-to-app/reset-password
```

Comment: do you add props option in your router file? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try `this.$route.query.token` instead of `this.$route.params` to get token from the url